Setting. state in useSubscription with observables
I have this hook
import { useObservable, useObservableState } from 'observable-hooks'


const tableUpdated = (table) => {
    const database = useDatabase();

    const data = useObservableState(
        useObservable(
            () => database.get(table).query().observe(),
            [],
        ),
    )
    return data;
};

export default tableUpdated;

Which I use the following
const Foo = () => {
    const posts = tableUpdated('posts')

    return <p>{posts.text}</p>
}

Now, what I actually need is something comparable to useEffect with a dependency on the table 'posts'. Whenever the table gets updated, I need the useEffect to run and perform some actions and finally set a local state.
According to the documentation you are supposed to use useSubscription. But I have no clue how to get the following (here: wrong with useEffect) running with useSubscription
const Foo = () => {
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null)
    const posts = tableUpdated('posts')

    useEffect(() => {
        if(posts) {
            const result = ... // do sth
            setFoo(result)
    }, [posts])

    return <p>{foo}</p>
}


useSubscription requires an Observable as its first argument. Here you're using useObservableState which "wraps" the observable into a react state.
If you can't modify tableUpdated to give you access to the observable, then you can't do much better than useEffect.
